# Null check for lambda expression tree

Tags: c#, lambda

How can I check if property of String type is null in order my following code to work and not fail during method calling ?

```
if (SelectedOperator is StringOperators)
{
    MethodInfo method;

    var value = Expression.Constant(Value);

    switch ((StringOperators)SelectedOperator)
    {
        case StringOperators.Is:
            condition = Expression.Equal(property, value);
            break;

        case StringOperators.IsNot:
            condition = Expression.NotEqual(property, value);
            break;

        case StringOperators.StartsWith:
            method = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
            condition = Expression.Call(property, method, value);
            break;

        case StringOperators.Contains:
            method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
            condition = Expression.Call(property, method, value);
            break;

        case StringOperators.EndsWith:
            method = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
            condition = Expression.Call(property, method, value);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case since property type is string, you can also check against it's default value (default value of reference type is always null). For e.g. you could do `Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Default(property.Type))`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a null check to the resultant expression using [`AndAlso`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353520(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
// Your switch stays as is
switch ((StringOperators)SelectedOperator) {
    case StringOperators.Is:
        condition = Expression.Equal(property, value);
        break;
    ...
}
// Create null checker property != null
var nullCheck = Expression.NotEqual(property, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object)));
// Add null checker in front of the condition using &&
condition = Expression.AndAlso(nullCheck, condition);
```

Comment: I tried    var nulloCheck = Expression.NotEqual(property, Expression.Constant(null));  
  condition = Expression.And(nulloCheck, condition);
But didnt help. I'll try with AndAlso as you suggested